# Doctrine paths not recognized in prod

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Ok, in dev enviroment Doctrine is working pretty well.
When I deploy the application to my production server, I got an error to include Doctrine as dependency to other files.

`require_once(Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/nifes651/public_html/www.mydomain.com.br/main/app/ConnectionFactory.class.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />`

Why am I getting this error?

Thank you all!

Comment: could you provide the pastie of /home/nifes651/public_html/www.mydomain.com.br/main/app/ConnectionFactory.class.php . Seems an autoloading issue to me. By the way how did you installed doctrine? If by composer did you ran to install the composer deps?

Comment: I just added Doctrine files from another project I had in this project. I solved the issue. I've added Doctrine one folder above of "app" folder and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved moving the "Doctrine" folder above the "app" folder, and then the files are recognizing properly.

Thank you all for the help.